# How to select directory and all subdirs

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I have the following file structure:

```
/var/www
/var/www/subdirectory
```

I want to configure my apache2.conf with a  directive that applies to both `var/www` and all it's subdirectories and files.

`<Directory "var/www">` only applies to the parent directory.

`Direcotry "var/www/*/">` only applies to the subdirectories.

**Clarification**

I am using https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache to try and configure apache2.conf. I therefore want all the changes to apply to every public file served (root dir and all other files).

When I read https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache, I get the understanding that `var/www` should apply to all subdirs, however the `Options -Indexes` rule clearly does not work (subdir indexes are visible). When I try `var/www/*` the indexes no longer show, but other rules are not applied to the root dir.

I can isolate this issue:

```
<Directory "var/www/*">

    <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Disables listing of subdirs, whereas:

```
<Directory "var/www">

    <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Does not.

** UPDATE 2 **

For reference, I have the following URL rewrites:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I apply the directive to both, and all included files?

Comment: AFAIK it will apply to all sub directories

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to be the case when testing though. Please see clarfication

Comment: You made something wrong. I would start to configure apache by myself rather than using some github cooked stuff. It's not that hard

Comment: This is not "github cooked". The problem applies when I isolate that issue, as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [`<Directory> Directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory)

> `<Directory>` and `</Directory>` are used to enclose a group of directives that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories.

Comment: I know, this doesn't appear the be the case though. Please see update.

Comment: @alias51: Do you have symbolic links in your `subdirectory`?

Comment: No, although I have a rewrite rule - `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: @alias51: This rewrite rules apply to _directory if not exists_ or _file if not exists_ or _link if not exists_ then requested URL will be substituted with `index.php?url=$1`.Flag `QSA` append query string from original request URL to query string created in rewrite target, flag `L` stop rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules.

Comment: thanks helpful but this doesn't explain why the Indexes option is not disabled?